# How can I rewrite my URLs so that all index.php files with a certain query are rewritten to https://example.com/<folder>/<query>

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create a Rewrite that rewrites the URLs in the following way:

`https://example.com/index.php?u=stack` -> `https://example.com/stack`;
`https://example.com/confirm/index.php?u=overflow` -> `https://example.com/confirm/overflow`

I have tried the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ /index.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?confirm(.*?)/?$ /confirm/index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

The first part, with the index.php, is rewritten correctly, however, the "confirm" part is not working. When I type https://example.com/confirm/overflow into my browser, I get a malformed (not styled) version of `https://example.com/overflow`. I think what is going wrong is that the first rewrite is still kicking in because "confirm" is not really a file, which causes the second rewrite not to fire.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can resolve this by reordering your rules put the second (specific)rule above the first  one.

Comment: @starkeen Thank you for your comment. I just tried what you suggested, but I get the following error: 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects'. It seems to put me in a redirect loop. Any idea?

Comment: No , it shouldn't cause that error  . Could you post  your current htaccess contents?

Comment: @starkeen Sure thing, here's my current .htaccess content: https://pastebin.com/U8VT2YpS

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen The only other thing I have in my .htaccess is `Options -Indexes`, but that should not make a difference. I also have a rewrite in my .conf file (to redirect non-https traffic to https): https://pastebin.com/9EP4yR3d. It only redirects when I visit https://example.com/confirm/<query>, and not when I visit https://example.com/<query>.

Comment: Do you get the infinite loop error only when going to the `/confirm` URI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191934/discussion-between-xxmarijnw-and-starkeen).